# Book accommodation at your hotel? is it right?

Tags: books

I was wondering if saying "book accommodation at your hotel" is right

or should I say, "book the hotel" or something like that.

thanks

Comment: To me a request to *"book the hotel"* somewhat implies booking the whole hotel (every available room). To "book accommodation" is correct but maybe a bit stilted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Book accommodation at your hotel" sounds a little strange.

Perhaps you could phrase it as:

> "I would like to reserve a (family/single/double) room for three nights."
>
> "I would like to book a hotel room."